# Meta Query being igored in WP

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

I am attempting a meta query to get between two prices set as a meta field in my custom post.

However the `_ccprop_prop_price` query is being ignored. Its still giving results higher than 100000 , I can confirm the id of the meta field is `_ccprop_prop_price`. It is worth noting however that the field is a `text` field not a `number` field.

Am I missing something obvious? I even tried to break it down further by doing two arrays and using `<` and `>` instead.

**Edit:** Just another development, I notice `=` does in fact work which makes me wonder is it something to do with it being a text field.

Here is the resulting final `$args`

```
(
[post_type] => property
[orderby] => meta_value_num
[meta_key] => _ccprop_prop_price
[order] => ASC
[posts_per_page] => 30
[paged] => 1
[tax_query] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
    )

[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => _ccprop_prop_price
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 100000
                    )

                [compare] => BETWEEN
                [type] => NUMERIC
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, there were commas for some of the prices in that meta field and they were the ones appearing.